# Creating child table of parent table using user other than admin in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have parent table CREATE TABLE named "user" suppose, that was creating by the superuser "postgres". 
Now I want to create child table of that parent table like

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_child
()
INHERITS (public.user)
```

But there are two issues. 1) I want to create that child using some other user, lets say "intern" that may not have privileges like super user. 2) I want to create that table dynamically in the function.

But it shows error that "intern" must be owner of "user" in order to create its child. 
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function owned by the superuser with `SECURITY DEFINER` that creates the new child table and then changes table ownership to `session_user`.

This will need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.

Revoke the `EXECUTE` privilege on this function from `PUBLIC` and grant it to the user that should be allowed to create the child table.

Comment: that makes some sense. But in my case there are multiple users and i am trying to maintain their logs in partitions. So I am dynamically checking the imcoming log along with the user name. In case the desired partition is not found, the partition would be created by the user from where this log entry is coming. As, parent is owned by superuser, other users can not create partitions dynamically.

Comment: BEGIN
      partition_date := to_char(NEW.date,'YYYY_MM');
      partition_name := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_date;
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition_name) THEN
        q :=' CREATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(partition_name) || ' () INHERITS parent;';
       EXECUTE q;
      END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;                                                                                                     This part of function gives ownership error if it was triggered by some user other than superuser.

Comment: Then do that in a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by the superuser. Where is the problem? I don't know what the "incoming log" is or "create a table by the user from where the log entry is coming". Instead of running the above code, you call the function I suggested.